# Leap Motion Visualizer embed into Windows form

Tags: c#, leap-motion, visualizer

Can anyone help me to embed leap motion visualizer into a c# windows form. What i need is in my windows form, the visualizer should be displayed, and then it should show my gestures, which were captured via the device

Answer (score 0):

The Leap Motion Visualizer program is not an embeddable object.

There are a few JavaScript visualizers ([see the Leap Motion example gallery](https://developer.leapmotion.com/gallery/category/javascript)) or you could write your own in C#.